# Android NDK C++ exception throws SIGSEGV and __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I want to throw a subclass of `std::exception` in my `JNI` code, the code is wrapped using swig but it's not really relevant since the generated code is rather simple:

```
void function_that_throws_exception() {
    ...
    throw MyNativeException("Error");
}

try {
    function_that_throws_exception();
} catch(MyNativeException &_e) {
    jclass excep = jenv->FindClass("x/y/zMyNativeException");
    if (excep)
        jenv->ThrowNew(excep, (&_e)->what());
    return 0;
}
```

I've added `-fexception` to flags but the vm still aborts when the user code throws the exception, the code in `catch` block is not executed.

I've tested different cpp implementations, `gnustl_static` raises `__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler`, looks like the exception is not handled,
`stlport_static` calls `abort()`

flags:

in `Android.mk`:
`LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions`

in `Application.mk`:
`APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions`
`APP_CFLAGS += -fexceptions`

I've also tried force rebuild of stlport and libcxx, and using `gcc-4.6`, `gcc-4.8` and `clang`

**UPDATE**

even this simple code aborts

```
try
{
    throw new std::exception();
} catch (std::exception &e) {
}
```

and if I set a termination function with `std::set_terminate`, my function get called, it's obviously not catched

**UPDATE**

simple code without "new" does work, so I suspect something is wrong with my exception:

```
class MyNativeException : public std::exception
{
public:
    explicit MyNativeException(const char *msg) : message(msg) {}
    virtual ~MyNativeException() throw() {}
    virtual const char *what() const throw() { return message.c_str(); }
protected:
    const std::string message;
};
```

I throw it using:
`throw MyNativeException("message")`

**UPDATE**
ok this exception definition does work:

```
class MyNativeException
{
public:
    MyNativeException(const char *msg) : message(msg) {}
    ~MyNativeException() {}
    const char *what() { return message.c_str(); }
private:
    const std::string message;
};
```

what's wrong in the previous?

Comment: `throw new std::exception();`  C++ is not Java.  Throw an exception object and catch it by reference.  What you're throwing there is a pointer.

Comment: See my answer below.  It explains how you would have caught the exception if you wanted to actually throw a pointer (which is rarely, if ever done in C++).

Answer (score 3):

Your issue has to do with confusing C++ with Java.

`throw new std::exception();`

That line above may be all well and good in Java, but is a different story in C++.

1. You are allocating memory from the free-store to create an object.
2. But most important, `new` in C++ returns a pointer that points to dynamically allocated memory that you must free using `delete`.  It is not the same as `new` in Java.

So that line of code in C++ is throwing a pointer value, not an object.  Unfortunately for you, you didn't detect this problem, since in C++ you can throw practically anything -- a `std::exception` object, an int, a pointer value, etc.

If you had a catch block that caught the pointer value, then you would see this.

For example:

```
try
{
   throw new std::exception();
} 
catch (std::exception *e) 
{
   delete e;
}
```

But to easily correct your attempt:

```
try
{
   throw std::exception();
} 
catch (std::exception &e) 
{
}
```

To confirm, here is a small, but full program that throws the exception and catches this:

```
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class MyNativeException : public std::exception
{
    public:
         explicit MyNativeException(const char *msg) : message(msg) {}
         virtual ~MyNativeException() throw() {}
         virtual const char *what() const throw() { return message.c_str(); }
    protected:
         const std::string message;
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw MyNativeException("abc123");
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

Output:
`abc123`

I took your class and actually threw the exception you're claiming doesn't get caught.  The exception in the code above does get caught, therefore the only conclusion to your issue is that you're either

1. Not throwing the exception you claim is being thrown, or
2. You're throwing it incorrectly (as pointed out by the issue with `new`), or
3. Your compiler is broken, or there is a switch you need to set to enable exception handling.

Comment: I used `new` only in the simple example, I've removed it while googling a bit (see update2), but my first example wasn't using `new`, the code using my exception it's still without `new`, but If I inherit from `std::exception` the catch does not work

Comment: @sherpya `the catch does not work` You haven't shown the actual code that invokes a throw of `MyNativeException`. What you have shown is a class called `MyNativeException` and a claim as to what is done, but not the actual code. In other words, this `function_that_throws_exception();` doesn't tell us anything.  No one knows what that function actually does or what it may actually throw.

Comment: I've added a sample function, anyway it's without `new` and if I don't inherit from `std::exception` it does work